# Omit controller name from URL mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, routes

I'm looking to do something similar to this post:

[How to hide controller name in Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380221/how-to-hide-controller-name-in-url)

only without any sort of ID.

The server is running IIS 6 and the pages already show up without extensions so it's not a wildcard issue.

I'm looking to hit http://website.com/action-name

I have http://website.com/controller/action-name working

I'm assuming this is just a simple routing change that I am somehow goofing up.  My current routing rule is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteName",
"{action}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your new routing rule positioned *above* the default routing rule of `{controller, action, id}` so that it has the opportunity to match *first*?

Comment: good point, ok is it mandatory to have  default route with action and id ? can i have only controller like this : `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
            );`

Comment: @stom: No, it's not mandatory, but it's a good idea.  The default routing rule gives the application a place to go if a route is presented that doesn't match any of the custom routes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your default route is still probably in place so it is matching it first and defaulting the rest of the inputs it expects.  Based on your comment that the `controller/action` is working makes me think you didn't remove it or it is appearing first.  Can you post your entire `RegisterRoutes`?

Try making the route you defined the very first route and it should match almost anything you pass at it.

**EDIT:** Added what your `RegisterRoutes` should look like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // This will match anything so if you have something very specific with hard coded
    // values or more items that will need to be match add them here above but do not
    // add defaulted values so it can still fall through to this.
    routes.MapRoute( 
        "RouteName", 
        "{action}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```