# MVC Route for a Single Controller to handle all Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a very basic ASP.NET MVC website that only contains one controller (HomeController) and all actions are contained within that controller.

Since there is only one controller, there is really no need to specify the "/Home" part of the url route, so I am looking for a route mapping that will allow me to infer the Home part of the URL for every request, for example:

http : // mysite.com/

```
HomeController {

   Public Action FooBar {}
   Public Action DoStuff {}

}
```

These Actions should resolve to these routes:

```
http : // mysite.com/FooBar

http : // mysite.com/DoStuff
```

should all auto resolve using the home controller.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What would the route config look like to allow me to leave out the controller name from the route (Infer the "/Home/" part of the URL).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169074/omit-controller-name-from-url-mvc

Comment: Yes, thanks @Robert Harvey - I wish I could mark this as the answer. In fact, if you make it an answer I will mark it as such. Thank you!