# how to have a single controller and action handle all routes in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have these paths:

```
 /r/dog 
 /r/dog/one 
 /r/dog/one/two 
 /r/dog/one/two/three
```

The path could go on like this pattern forever.

I want just one controller and one action to handle all these requests. How do I configure an ASP.NET Core route to handle this requirement?

I tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169074/omit-controller-name-from-url-mvc) instructions but they didn't work.

Tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute("r", "/r/{action}", new {controller = "Dashboard", action="Index" });
```

Comment: I want any path that starts with "r" to go to a single action in a single controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx.
There is a section called: Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern

You need to annotate your controller and action to match the following pattern:
query/{queryname}/{*queryvalues}

For example

```
    [Route("r")]
    public sealed class PageController : Controller
     {
    [Route("{*queryvalues}")]
     public IActionResult Index()
        { 
          return View();

        }
      }
```