# ASP MVC 5 Hide Area in URL (Routes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three areas: `tpl1 - tpl2 - tpl3`

And when I start the application I choose which area to use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        new[] { "LojaOnline.Controllers" }
        ).DataTokens.Add("area", "tpl1");
```

(The "tpl1" in DataTokens.Add is dynamic.)

The Url is: `http://localhost/tpl1/Home/Index`

I need to hide the name of the area in the URL. Something like that:

The Url is: `http://localhost/Home/Index`

I have this in `tpl1AreaRegistration.cs`

```
context.MapRoute(
            "tpl1_default",
            "tpl1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But if I remove the tpl1, the application doesn't know which controller use.

```
context.MapRoute(
            "tpl1_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: You might find this question-answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380221/how-to-hide-controller-name-in-url

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know in IIS its not possible.

When you give the URL to be `http://localhost/Home/Index`.
First it will connect to your local IIS and inside which it will search for the Application Name as "`Home`" and inside it will search for the scripting page or webforms as per the Web application which you choose. But actually as per your URL you have specified your application to be **tpl1**.

So you cannot use `http://localhost/Home/Index` instead of `http://localhost/tpl1/Home/Index`

But yes you can hide the `Index` from the URL at the end like `http://localhost/tpl1/Home`. 
Using Route file you can only control the URL's inside the application.